# Webpack not watching some files in an Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, webpack

I have a basic Angular 2 app that is using Webpack.
Webpack picks up most of the changes correctly however it misses some folders. I can't work out why and have been looking at this for 2 days now.

I have a folder in the solution as below that contains a Angular component. Webpack finds that one perfectly...

```
src/app/shared/profile
```

However another component at a similar path is ignored...

```
src/app/shared/tiles
```

Why would Webpack do this?

I am using my main.ts as the app entry point. The app uses both of the components.

If anyone is interested and can help me the GitHub repo for the project is here...

[Github repo for project](https://github.com/bencameron00/TileCase.V2.UI)

Comment: Do you import tiles from any place ? I can find you use it anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean the tiles component?

Comment: yes. or you are talking about service ?

Comment: What do you mean misses some folders? I just cloned your repo and it seems to work fine, though I had to tweak the webpack-dev-server command to include a `config` file option.

Comment: Oh what was the config change you made?

Comment: There is a possibility that you didn't restart the webpack after adding tiles.service

Comment: Its the component name tiles.component.ts that's not being picked up. I've restarted many times I'm afraid.

Comment: In `package.json`, I added `--config config/webpack.dev.js` to the  `"start"` script.

Comment: I've also cloned your repo, made a change in your package.json to add config option for webpack-dev-server: { "start": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --inline --progress --content-base src/" } and when I make a change to shared/tiles component, it updates the change. Not sure what is going on in your end...

Comment: Thanks for the config idea but its made no difference. When I edit tiles.component.ts no change is picked up in the node bash window. Also interestingly when I do a prod build and deploy it I see an 404 error in the browser where its looking for tiles.component.html but can't find it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error I'm afraid. Works fine here. Working in OS X El Capitan.

Comment: Is the code you're using ahead of the code that is in your master branch? Perhaps, you can try cloning your own repo and then try again. I just also ran the code in your master branch in production and it works fine.

Comment: The app runs fine how ever the bundle doesn't get make invalid in the node window on a file change to tiles.component.ts. Are you guys seeing that happen?

Comment: This doesn't happen for me. Webpack was able to successfully recompile the files for me and the change does show up on my browser. Not sure what is going on over there

Comment: Ok blowing it all away and have rebuilt from the repo and it seems to work now. Not sure why but that's good. Thank you for your help and suggestions everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok blowing it all away and have rebuilt from the repo and it seems to work now. Not sure why but that's good. Thank you for your help and suggestions everyone.